# How to merge multiple SVGs files on a html page?

Tags: svg

I have been trying to merge two SVG files into single SVG file. Everywhere I found is using pageSet. Below code is to merge two SVG file to a single file.

```
<pageSet>
    <page>
        <circle cx="300" cy="150" r="90" fill="red" stroke="black"
                stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0.7" />
    </page>
    <page>
        <circle cx="240" cy="250" r="90" fill="green" stroke="black"
                stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0.7" />
    </page>
    <page>
        <circle cx="360" cy="250" r="90" fill="blue" stroke="black"
                stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0.7" />
    </page>
</pageSet>
```

I tried using the above code but, nothing is displaying.

Comment: How are you trying to display it - in a browser? Presumably the above isn't the whole of the file - an SVG file needs to be in `<svg>` tags. How are you merging the files?

Comment: This looks like it's using SVG Print, http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGPrint12/, that spec is still a working draft and there's no on-going work to finish it. None of the web browsers support it AFAIK.

Comment: What is your goal in merging the two files? Are you trying to display them side-by-side, or with the contents of the second (and third, etc.) files overlaid on the same graphic?

Comment: @halfer, Sorry I pasted the incomplete code. the above code should be within <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2"></svg>   Tag

Comment: @Phrogz, I have some svg file around 30 pages, I need to display altogether in the browser one page after another like a pdf file.

Comment: @Dalee - no worries. Please edit the question with that correction, and I'll happily undownvote.

Comment: In terms of displaying these docs, would it be acceptable to convert the pages to a bitmap format using a SVG renderer, such as Inkscape, and then just display the bitmaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can embed SVG files in an HTML document, one after another. For example, with either the SVG content inline:

```html
<html><head>…</head><body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><!-- SVG Data --></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><!-- SVG Data --></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><!-- SVG Data --></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><!-- SVG Data --></svg>
</body></html>
```

…or [referencing an external file](http://www.schepers.cc/svg/blendups/embedding.html):

```html
<html><head>…</head><body>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="file1.svg"></object>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="file2.svg"></object>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="file3.svg"></object>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="file4.svg"></object>
</body></html>
```

You can then use CSS to [control the page breaks when printing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/page-break-before):

```css
svg, object { page-break-before:always }
```

Comment: Phrogz, Ive one more doubt. I need to convert the outcome html file generated after embeding all the svg files into pdf file. I tried the conversion in java using a sample html file containing svg elements, but I am unable to view the svg graphics.

Comment: @Dalee Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm glad to have helped. Note that your followup question should be [posted as a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to get proper exposure and help; something like _"Converting HTML file with SVG to PDF"_. Note that if (and only if!) you feel that this answer has fully solved the question you asked, you should [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/153741). This helps your reputation, my reputation, and also indicates to other users with a similar question that this answer is helpful.

Comment: OK I am new to stackoverflow. I can't see any symbol or button as accepted. Can you guide me how to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Dalee No problem! Click the link on "mark it as accepted" that I provided above; it explains how to do it. :)

Comment: Just for idea. If you want to merge the files with pixel perfection (because you have 2 or more different sized svg file, just try to use some vector based editor, like the free inkscape)